# C# Windows Phone 8.1 Twitter Authentication Page Not Changing

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following c# code for windows phone 8.1 to authenticate user login via twitter.

openTwitterPage is the Button event when user clicks login on the home page.

After the user enter his login credentials on twitter page and clicks sign in, my homepage is shown again and the Frame.Navigate code is never executed.

```
    private async void openTwitterPage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Authenticate();
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainMenu));
    }

    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Authenticate()
    {
        user = await  App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Twitter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles using MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider too so I wrote my own library to authenticate users with Twitter client-side on Windows Phone 8.1. Take a look - https://github.com/konradbartecki/TwitterAutherino